# Read Response From Json Post Call Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In the `java` app we get response from the REST as String by using de below code.

```
String response = performPostCall(wmeAPI.vote("" + rowItem.getPoll_id()), has);
```

In swift I am making post call with `Alamofire`

I made post call

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding:.JSON).responseString
            { response in switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    print("Success \(JSON)")
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    }
        }
```

How can I get the response string from this post call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use response JSON

So, Change `responseString` to `responseJSON`

For Example :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "YOUR_URL").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        print(swiftyJsonVar)
    }
}
```

For POST call :

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "YOUR_URL", parameters: nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

    print(responseObject)

    if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
        let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
        print(resJson)
    }
    if responseObject.result.isFailure {
        let error : NSError = responseObject.result.error!
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: can I apply this .POST call ?

Comment: @tmac99 yes ... why not you can use any of this `GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT`

Answer (score 2):

if you check `Alamofire` Doc., there is already define the things that how to get response String and how to get response JSON

**Response JSON handler**

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
     .responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)
     }
```

**Response String handler**

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
     .responseString { response in
         print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
         print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
     }
```

**Chained Response Handlers**

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
     .responseString { response in
         print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
     }
     .responseJSON { response in
         print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")
     }
```

Refer [Alamofire Usage](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)